# Prevent generating @FK attributes

Tags: telosys

How can I prevent @FK attributes from not being created when generating the model?

Since the primary keys are not defined, but only constraints, the files cannot be generated later.

> [ERROR] : Invalid model 'TestModel' Converter error : Entity tContact:
> tOwnerid : FK error : 'titemid' is not a ID/PK attribute in entity
> 'tAccount' Cannot load model => stopping code generation.

The following is already defined in databases.yaml:

- linksOneToMany: false
- linksManyToOne: false
- linksManyToMany: false

I use Telosys V 4.1.0-001.

Answer (score 0):

In the current Telosys version it's not possible to prevent FK definitions when the model is automatically created from a database.
But the mentionned error is triggered when the model is loaded.

So, for now (as a workaround) you can manually edit the entities (".entity" files) that contains invalid FK and remove "@FK" annotation.